# What Diagrams backends support animation?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

In the [diagrams tutorial](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/cmdline.html#introduction) the following text appears:

> Some backends support rendering animations (typically as individually indexed files of frames).
>
> ```
> > -- Animation
> >
> > a :: Animation Cairo V2 Double
> > a = ...
> >
> > main = mainWith a
> ```

So from here I started working on a little animation.  I found [`Diagrams.Animation`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4.2.2/docs/Diagrams-Animation.html) and discovered that the `Animation` type is

```
type Animation b v n = Active (QDiagram b v n Any)
```

From there I looked at `Data.Active`, and was able to build myself a little `Animation`.

At this point I attempted to compile but was told that my `Animation` was not `Mainable`.  I supposed that this must mean that my backend `Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine` did not support animations.  So I went and looked at some other backends, but none that I could find made `Animation`s `Mainable`.

What backends is the tutorial talking about?  That is, what backends support animation?

Comment: From a quick skim at the docs for diagrams I found that both the `Cairo` backend and the `Rasterific` backend define a `Mainable (Animation ...)`. And I may have missed a few more.

Comment: Animations are really backend-agnostic. An animation is basically just a function from time to a diagram of whatever backend you desire. Use [simulate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/active-0.2.0.13/docs/Data-Active.html#v:simulate) to obtain discrete snapshots of such an animation.

Answer (score 0):

`diagrams-cairo` and `diagrams-rasterific` can produce animated GIFs from an `Animation`.  `diagrams-postscript` has a `Mainable` instance that saves one numbered file for each frame of the `Animation`.